# How can I display a blog on the frontend, which is created by using trix?

Tags: php, laravel, trix

In the blade I am using this code:

```
<td>{{ $blog->content }}</td>
```

but the output on the blade.php is unfortunately:

```
<div>fascawds def ef edf&nbsp;<em>e df</em> dfg dfdx<strong>df&nbsp; dfxgfdgdf gefdger fdgerfd df&nbsp;</strong></div>
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `{{!! $blog->content !!}}` to display any html content.